# MSGraph OData filtering on empty collections

Tags: powershell, odata, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the MS powershell modules for working with MsGraph, but the same rules/principles apply when providing a filter as to what you'd normally just put into the http query string.

I have the following which works okay and lists all 365groups that are teams:

```
Get-MgGroup -Filter "resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team')"
```

What I would like to acheive, without having to pull ALL groups and then filtering locally, is basically the opposite of the above, something like this:

```
Get-MgGroup -Filter "resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x ne 'Team')"
```

But because I'm doing this against a collection, it throws.

```
Get-MgGroup_List: Unsupported property filter clause operator 'NotEqualsMatch'.
```

Now I've tried every which way I an think of to get this to work, I've tried looking for a set of operators that would effectivly filter if resourceProvisioningOptions is null/empty as a collection. But nothing I try will work, I just seem to get errors. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#group-properties) `resourceProvisioningOptions` is not nullable and not filterable using `null`.

`ne` negation operators are supported only with advanced queries which means that you need to add `-ConsistencyLevel "eventual"` and `-CountVariable` or `-CountVariable "<number>"` (I'm not familiar with Graph API SDK for PowerShell) parameters

```
Get-MgGroup -Filter "resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x ne 'Team')" -ConsistencyLevel "eventual" -CountVariable "100"
```

Comment: This doesnt look to work either, the response was: `Get-MgGroup_List1: Using 'ne' inside 'any' clause is invalid. Suggestion: consider using the 'not' operator instead. For example: $filter=not groupTypes/any(x:x eq 'Unified')`
However, it's pointed me in the right direction: 
`Get-MgGroup -Filter "not resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team')" -ConsistencyLevel "eventual" -CountVariable "100"`
Seems to do the trick, downside is it then prevents me from using -ExpandProperty Owners. I'll leave this as the answer as it might help some, but it's still a no go for me!